# Call back with two parameters ES6 Arrow Function Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback, ecmascript-6

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong with my callback function?
I need to pass a parameter to the function to check and when it is done checking it sends back true or false.

```
CheckPlayer(cb,player){
   if(player >0){ 
      console.log("true");
      cb(true);
     }
   else{
      console.log("False");
      cb(false);
      }
}

 //This comes up with many errors
 //The main typescript error says: ',' expected
 CheckMe(){
    player=10;
    isGreat:Boolean;
    this.CheckPlayer((isGreat,player) => {
      if(isGreat)
        console.log("Truth");
      else
        console.log("Fase");
     });
   }
```

Comment: You aren't passing the first parameter to this.checkPlayer();
You are passing the callback as the first parameter, and then the second param which should be the callback is undefined.

Comment: Get rid of the syntax errors first.

Comment: @carmouch okay I switched the two, but still the same errors

Comment: @Pointy I cleaned it up a little, sorry

Comment: The typescript error that keeps popping up is: ',' expected

Answer (score 3):

Look at the signature

```
CheckPlayer(cb,player){
```

There are two different arguments you need to pass. One is the callback, and the other is the player. You are trying pass only one argument, the callback, and adding the player as a callback parameter. That's not how it works.

Simple pass the callback and the player as arguments to the `CheckPlayer`, just like you would any other arguments, separated by comma

```
this.CheckPlayer((isGreat) => {
  if(isGreat)
    console.log("Truth");
  else
    console.log("Fase");
 }, player);
```

Though usually you have the callback as the last parameter. It just makes for cleaner looking code

```
CheckPlayer(player, cb){


this.CheckPlayer(player, (isGreat) => {
  if(isGreat)
    console.log("Truth");
  else
    console.log("Fase");
 });
```

[**Playground**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Demo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20CheckPlayer(cb%2Cplayer)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if(player%20%3E0)%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22true%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20cb(true)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22False%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20cb(false)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20CheckMe()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20let%20player%3D10%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20let%20isGreat%3ABoolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20this.CheckPlayer((isGreat)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20if(isGreat)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Truth%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Fase%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20player)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Demo().CheckMe())

Comment: Im still getting the same errors when I try to call the function. Still says its expecting a ','

Comment: You need to use `let` or `var` for the variables `player` and `isGreat` at the top of the `CheckMe` method. That's the only error I'm getting

Comment: Yeah for some reason this just was not working for me. Thank you though I really appreciate it, I ended up just using a promise instead

Comment: Check out my playground link at the bottom